# different between stop animate and animate

Tags: jquery

What are the differences between **.stop().built-in_func** and **.built-in_func** like these:

```
$('selector').stop().animate({//code to be executed});


$('selector').animate({//code to be executed});
```

Comment: The jQuery api clearly defines the difference: http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $('selector').stop().animate({//code to be executed});

This line first stop any running animation on matched elements (by selector) and then start a new animation by calling the `animate(...)` function

> $('selector').animate({//code to be executed});

But this line start a animation that can be overlapped with other running animations(if queue sets to false). and when queue sets to true it waits for other running animation on matched elements and once them is terminared starts new animation.

Please see this fiddle to understand difference:
http://jsfiddle.net/N69sV/

Answer (score 3):

One stops any currently playing animations before animation, and the other doesn't.